# Send Data packages over UDP

Tags: perl, sockets, udp, send, storable

I'm trying to send a scalar value over socket which I have got with nfreeze from storable.
Step by step:

1. I get the scalar
   `$serializedHash = nfreeze \%hash;`
2. I want to send it over socket `$sendSocket->send($serializedHash);`

This works fine, as long as the scalar `$serializedHash` is not bigger than 1024byte. Because I have on the other side a socket which can only receive data with max. length of 1024byte.
I also cannot store `$serializedHash` in a file and then handle it with `sysread` and `syswrite`.

What I don't want is to send every single line per socket, bacause my Hash has over 2 million entries. The hash element are seperated by a `\n` so I tried with the `split` function, but then I have a array with 2 million entries.

How can I send data in packages through a UDP socket?

Comment: Why UDP? It's really really not up to the task. (See my comment to raina77ow's answer for details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may possibly process your serialized hash by chunks, like that:

```
while ($serializedHash =~ /(.{1,1024})/sg) {
  my $chunk = $1;
  # sending $chunk
}
```

Comment: please explain it a litle bit more =)

Comment: As I understand, you need to split your big string into smaller parts, then send them through UDP one by one. What I suggested is actually a pretty ordinary solution: while ($string =~ /$pattern/g) loop. The $pattern is matched over the string again and again, each time starting from the position it finished earlier. As it's greedy by default, it captures 1024 symbols - or whatever is remaining.

Comment: BTW, there's a potential bug here: as we should process the bytes, not the characters, perhaps 'use bytes' directive should be introduced as well.

Comment: That's far from a complete solution. Unlike, UDP does not guarantee that packets will be received arrive in the order they were sent, so you'll have to number the chunks. And you'll have to coordinate the number of chunks so it knows when to stop listening. And so on. In other words, you have to (effectively) reimplement TCP over UDP.

Comment: @raina77ow, No, never use `use bytes`. The characters of the strings are bytes, so splitting the string into chunks of 1024 characters is the same thing as splitting the string into chunks of 1024 bytes. It does need a /s (added) to avoid mishandling byte 0A.

Comment: Greetings Overflower :)
thank you very much for you help.
@raina77ow
after your first comment i was searching for something like this:
http://www.sarand.com/td/ref_perl_pattern.html

It's the first time that I see such a Patern, but now it all makes sense :)

ikegami
dont worry about the UDP packages this will  be another part of my work. But before i got to fix some other problems